# How to bevel and inset a loop on the edge of a model?

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I have beveled some edges in the mesh and then inset and increased depth so they get pushed in to create a "cut" in effect as shown in the first image [image]

However, I seemed to have forgotten to select the edges in the second picture while doing this and now I am not sure how to achieve the same thing i did in the first picture in these edges (there are no autosaves)[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the object? pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Hello. i cannot share the entire model as it is a game asset however I can share the part in question https://pasteall.org/blend/162e8063422f4fedb99d88b49b4a1f80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest effect you can have to what you did above is to bevel the side as such:
[image]

EDIT: to get an even closer effect:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, while it does get the same bevel effect it doesnt get the inset i wanted and depth i want it to achieve. I do appreciate the answer though.

Comment: I see now what youre trying to do. ill update answer

Comment: It does seem to get close to the effect however there is one edge that seems to be really messed up, I think if this gets fixed it should be fixed all together (added image to show what i mean.